# Which is better Binary Serialization or XML Serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

If i have a class that contains some string, int and List type properties and I want to store that class object into my physical disc. So, which method is better performance wise and  file size wise.

Comment: Binary serialization will definitely be more efficient in space (memory and disk), and I think it's safe to say more efficient in time as well. However, it is less flexible than XML.

Comment: I would use JSON, it's more compact than XML and supported by any other language

Comment: It depends. Binary Serialization is faster than XML (and takes less space), but is less flexible.

Comment: Binary, definitely :) Look on this one(free) http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html

Comment: @pwas Wow, I never thought of that before!

Comment: what's  business backgrond ,if you want to see the serialize result ,I will choose XML

Comment: @Uriil I am winform developer and I don't have much knowledge about JSON.So, can i use it in C# with winform?

Comment: @Nimesh Sure, look at json.net project(http://json.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no correct answer really. Performance-wise the binary method is faster and the file size will be smaller, XML well be slower to parse and will have a bigger size because of it adds "metadata" to describe things.

But it really a question of application, the XML is human-readable and more universal while the binary format depends on your implementation of it and cannot be read by others if they don't have your program/specification for this file (unless of course they reverse engineer it...)

Also binary format gives you more freedom in a matter of compression/encryption etc...

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on the context. If you have two applications using same data, you might use `Binary Serialization` which is `faster but less flexible`. But in case of different systems, like one in C# another in Python, XML serialization is more appropriate for its `flexibility`. And you have to keep performance issues in mind. So, there is always a tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jonathon and Urilil.
While binary is more efficient for performance and file size, I would not recommend to use it.
You will face two issues : 
- i case of a bug, how do you know if the bug  is in the write or in the read side ?
- when your class evolves (and it will), you might not be able to read old files whith last version of your application

So, use XML or JSON.
if you still need binary, have a look at protocol buffers